# Pass File Name to Program

Tags: vb.net

I am making an application in VB.NET and I am attempting to pass the double-clicked file's name into the application, so I can set the application's title to it. I need to find the method to retrieve this, yet I cannot seem to do so. I just want to know, really, if/how I can retrieve the name of the file that was opened in this application.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)) 'Set TextBox Text to file text
        Me.Text = "SHDO v2.0 - " + 'Here should go the opened file title
        editedYet = False 'Disable title asterisk
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Does "file title" mean file name?   There is a lot of code there that has nothing to do with the question.  What is not working in that Form Load event?

Comment: `Me.Text = "SHDO v2.0 - " & Path.GetFileName(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0))`

Comment: @Plutonix I've edited the question and clarified it, but yes, I did intend to say "file name". I've also deleted the unnecessary code, and the form load event works, I just need help with finding the opened file's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
    Dim filePath As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)
    TextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath)
    Me.Text = "SHDO v2.0 - " & IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)
```

If you don't want the file extension, you could use `IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` instead.

Hope that helps :)